# Issue with CD index not being updated after updating CM for Sitecore 8.1

Tags: indexing

I have the following setup

- 1 CM server
- 1 CD server
- Sitecore 8.1

We have a custom Lucene index that is updating with no problem on our CM server but not on our CD server.   I checked the logs and it doesn't seem to show anything that would be related to this issue.   I also checked that the index was added to the EventQueue table and it is added to this table to run.  The instance names for the StabilitySettings.config are the same.   This was working fine yesterday and suddenly stopped working today and no new code changes were added.  When I check the Crawling log on the CD server I only see the following text

IndexCustodian. FullRebuild triggered on index {MyIndexName}

I don't see where it is adding the items or starting and stopping the crawl.

Any one have any ideas where I can look at to see what might be happening?

I am thinking about copying the index from CM to CD as a temp solution for now.

Update: We applied `SwitchMasterToWeb` script and cannot login into CD now.

Comment: Have you tried manually rebuilding your index from the control panel?

Comment: What db are you using for event queue storage?  (core by default) And are you CM and CD instances connecting to the same database for that - or is there replication involved? (for instance if your CM and CD each have their own core db).

Comment: We have the CD and CM using the same core database.

Comment: On CD I can't get to the control panel based on the way we have setup CD on the server.   I was thinking of creating a aspx file under sitecore/admin that I could run when I want to force it to rebuild the index.

Answer (score 3):

I would check to ensure that your CD and CM servers system time are all in sync.  I've seen a difference of just a few seconds cause issues with remote events/event queue.

Comment: I suppose that since a Sitecore process checks the event queue every 2 seconds, a few seconds could matter. I never really considered that until I read your comment.

Comment: We do have the event queue checking every 2 seconds I might want to add more time to it in case it was running into some issue that needed those few seconds.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure what happened but after doing updating our index the 7th time it started to work correctly.

Comment: You sure nothing changed in the meantime?